# Problem with using Python via R's reticulate in Docker container

Tags: python, r, docker, reticulate

I create a Docker image based on `rocker/shinyverse`with the Dockerfile:

```
# File: Dockerfile
FROM rocker/shiny-verse:4.2.2

RUN echo "apt-get start"
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
python3 \
python3-pip 

# install R packages
RUN R -e "install.packages('remotes')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('reticulate')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('tidyverse')"

# Install Python packages datetime and zeep
RUN python3 -m pip install datetime zeep

# Set the environment variable to use Python3
ENV RETICULATE_PYTHON /usr/bin/python3
```

Then I have the simple R file:

```
library("tidyverse")
library(reticulate)

# Call a simple Python command to calculate 3*5
py_run_string("z = 3+4")
py$z %>% print()
```

After I launched the container, I want to run this R script with the shell command:

```
docker exec shiny_new Rscript /home/shiny/ETL/reticulate_test.R
```

but I get the following error:

```
Error: Python shared library not found, Python bindings not loaded.
Use reticulate::install_miniconda() if you'd like to install a Miniconda Python environment.
Execution halted
```

It fails when executing the python

I am unsure how to setup the Python in such a way that I can use python code via `reticulate` in my R script. Does anybody have an idea where I go wrong in setting up the Docker image?

Comment: Did my answer solved your doubts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Folowing [this issue](https://github.com/rstudio/reticulate/issues/952), it seems `pyenv` installs Python without the Python shared library.

You should try to add:

- `reticulate::install_python()` which wraps `pyenv` and set `--enable-shared` option

or

- set the `--enable-shared` variable as [suggested here](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki#how-to-build-cpython-with---enable-shared)